# ¿Como puedo agregar QCustomPlot a mi proyecto de Qt que usa CMake para compilar?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Estoy queriendo agregar la clase qcustomplot para ser usada en un proyecto el cual compila con cmake del cual se muy muy poco al respecto.

He probado agregar las siguientes lineas a CMakeLists.txt segun lo que he leido en varios sitios pero no tuve exitos para compilarlo.

```
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS PrintSupport REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(statistics-calculator PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt6::PrintSupport)
```

Pero no he tenido exito a la hora de compilarlo, los errores que me arroja son los siguientes:

[image: error]

[image: error]

Software QT Creator: Qt Creator 5.0.0-rc1 (4.84.0)
Version de QT: 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es recomendable incluir qcustomplot como una libreria por lo que el proyecto puede tener la siguiente estructura:

```
├── 3rdparty
│   └── qcustomplot
│       ├── changelog.txt
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── GPL.txt
│       ├── qcustomplot.cpp
│       └── qcustomplot.h
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)

project(qcustomplot_test VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(qcustomplot_test
  main.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(3rdparty/qcustomplot)

target_link_libraries(qcustomplot_test PRIVATE
  Qt6::Widgets
  qcustomplot
)
```

3rdparty/qcustomplot/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS PrintSupport REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
add_library(qcustomplot STATIC qcustomplot.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qcustomplot PRIVATE Qt6::PrintSupport)
target_include_directories(qcustomplot INTERFACE .)
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include "qcustomplot.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QCustomPlot plot;
    plot.resize(640, 480);
    plot.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Lo tendre en cuenta para proximos proyectos, al final termine descargando una version 5 y algo y eso me sirvio para hacer funcionar qcustomplot en mi aplicacion. Por lo que lei se debe a falta de soporte para la version 6 de Qt, me imagino en unas semanas se solucionara, de todas formas para mi proximo proyecto seguire tu consejo a ver si me funciona, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @IgnacioBelitzky Si quieres desarrollar algo estable en Qt6 entonces espera la versión 6.2 ya que será la primera version LTS, pero si quieres aprender entonces es suficiente con la versión actual de Qt6